# PHP how to make one sqaure bracket for all json object

Tags: php, arrays, json

The below is my php code.Many thanks

```
$data = array();
 foreach ($row as $rowk) {
  $data[] = array(
      'message'   => $row['traditionalmessage'],
      'phone'   => $row['telMobile']

      );
      break;
 }

echo json_encode($data);
```

My current result

```
[{"message":"B\u578b\u809d\u708e\u75ab\u82d7\u4e0b\u4e00\u500b\u6ce8\u5c04\u671f\u4e3a2017-06-30\r\n","phone":"96709394"}][{"message":"\u75ab\u82d7\u540d\u7a314\u4e0b\u4e00\u500b\u6ce8\u5c04\u671f\u4e3a2017-06-30\r\n","phone":"96709394"}][{"message":"\u4fe1\u606f","phone":"55503234"}]
```

My desired result

```
[{"message":"B\u578b\u809d\u708e\u75ab\u82d7\u4e0b\u4e00\u500b\u6ce8\u5c04\u671f\u4e3a2017-06-30\r\n","phone":"96709394"},{"message":"\u75ab\u82d7\u540d\u7a314\u4e0b\u4e00\u500b\u6ce8\u5c04\u671f\u4e3a2017-06-30\r\n","phone":"96709394"},{"message":"\u4fe1\u606f","phone":"55503234"}]
```

Comment: Try removing the `[]` after the second `$data`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. This will only generate a single item in the array because you have `break`. If I remove it, I get the result you describe as desired.

Comment: @CTravel — That will cause `$data` to be **overwritten** by the new array, not appended to.

Comment: @Quentin true,, just to tried to reproduce the problem.. Indeed its not possible to reproduce his error..

Answer (score 0):

In JSON arrays represented in [], and objects in {}, so in desired case you should have array of objects while you have array of arrays.
Try something like this:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($row as $rowk) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->message = $row['traditionalmessage'];
    $obj->phone = $row['telMobile'];

    $data[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```